# 2m Homebrew Receiver - Chip for frequency

Tags: diy, receiver, equipment-design, vhf, 2m-band

I am a new HAM trying to design a small, cheap 2m receiver.  I've been looking up different circuits and homebrew tutorials, but the closest I seem to find to what I'm looking for seems to always use a MK484 chip.  That chip covers 150 kHz to 3 MHz.  I'm only licensed as a Technician at the moment and can't use any bands within that range.

Is there a chip out there that fits into a simple, one chip circuit, but reaches 144 MHz?  If not, is there a homebrew design out there you could recommend?  If not, where do I start?
I'm looking for something simple to get me started.

Comment: Hi LauraD, and welcome to the Amateur Radio SE and Stack Exchange. We will likely be happy to help you out, but it seems that this question is not yet a great fit for our question-and-answer format. You talk about a single-chip receiver design, but in my experience, that's not what homebrew tutorials are about (most tend to use discrete components and a minimum of, if indeed any, ICs). You say you are looking for a "simple, one chip circuit" that reaches 144 MHz, but you don't say what you want to use it for in your design.

Comment: The question "where do I start?" is also fairly broad, which is something we generally try to avoid on Stack Exchange; the site works best when questions are possible to answer authoritatively, and the answers can be judged on their technical merits in relation to the specific issue the asker wants help with. If you can **[edit]** your question to address these issues, we will be much more likely to be able to provide good answers that actually solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Si4460 chipset may help you with some low power stuff and alternatively small USB-based SDR receivers like the R820T could be of use..

Answer (score -1):

Try a Google search for "2m receiver chip" or "receiver chip 144MHz". Then refine your search to Images - you should see thumbnail pictures of schematics.
After that, it's a matter of browsing for a circuit that looks small & simple...
[like](http://www.qsl.net/va3iul/Homebrew_RF_Circuit_Design_Ideas/RX_144MHz_FM_PU2XJE.gif) [these](http://taha.islam-piers.org/circuits/2M-Circuits/modified-ckt-with-squelch.htm).

Comment: Hi Alan. While this may in theory answer the question, we want answers on the Stack Exchange network to be self-contained. Links to external references for *complementary* or reference material are perfectly acceptable, but even disregarding all links, an answer posted here should still provide an answer to the question as asked, which I don't see this answer doing. Please [edit] your answer to expand on it such that it answers the question, keeping in mind any copyright or licensing issues; thank you.

Comment: It would seem I have been downgraded, for only answering the "where do I start" portion of the question. Obviously I need to understand the posting system better, and add schematics of single-chip circuits [rather than linking to them].

Comment: The problem with your answer, Alan, is that it is completely dependent on non-StackExchange resources. As it says in the [Stack Exchange Tour](http://stackexchange.com/tour), "We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers". This answer doesn't help do that, because it simply tells the asker *where else to look* rather than *answering their question*. Compare [meta.se] discussions [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/157730) and [when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/157730).